# How can I prevent I/O redirection from silently failing upon modifying the file elsewhere?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I'm trying to write a simple shell script to start a program running in the background and redirect all its output to a log file, but I've come across a case where it silently fails and kills the program.

It happens if the file that's being redirected into is modified elsewhere. I've tried recreating the situation using the ping command so I can narrow the problem down to not being my program's code, but that fails in a different way - it stops writing to the file, but the terminal still acts as though the ping is running.

This is the essence of my code:

```
sh "$program" > "$file"
```

Comment: You are actually `re-direct`ing the command's ouput (`> file`) not piping it (`cmd 1 | cmd 2`)

Comment: @Inian ah yeah, I always get those mixed up. Edited